# Create ICS with objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am writing an app for students at my university. At this point I want to export the lessons in the schedule as an ics-file. I have wrote something that works with csv-files, but now I want the same for ics.
The problem is that iCal at my Mac doesn't want the in-app-created ics-files from this code:

```
    -(NSURL*)getFileUrl
{
    NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stundenplan-%@.ics", _MatrNr]];
    NSURL *fileUrl     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];


    NSError *error = nil;
    [[self getICSData] writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error while writing to File: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return fileUrl;
}

-(NSData*)getICSData
{
    NSMutableString *erg = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSDate *aktDatum = [NSDate date];

    [erg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//www.htw-dresden.de//iOS//DE\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\n"]];


    for (Stunde *this in _daten) {
        NSString *titel = [this.titel stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\\, "];
        NSString *dozent = [this.dozent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\\, "];

        NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

        [erg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:%@\n", uuid]];
        [erg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DTSTART:%@T%@Z\n",[self nurTagFromDate:this.anfang], [self nurUhrzeigFromDate:this.anfang]]];
        [erg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DTEND:%@T%@Z\n",[self nurTagFromDate:this.ende], [self nurUhrzeigFromDate:this.ende]]];
        [erg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LAST-MODIFIED:%@T%@Z\nSEQUENCE:0\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\n", [self nurTagFromDate:aktDatum], [self nurUhrzeigFromDate:aktDatum]]];
        [erg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUMMARY:%@\nDESCRIPTION:%@\nLOCATION:%@\nEND:VEVENT\n", titel, dozent, this.raum]];
    }

    [erg appendString:@"END:VCALENDER"];

    NSData *ret = [erg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return ret;
}
```

In the getFileUrl I want to return a URL to the file created in there. This function calls the getICSData function that goes through my array (_daten) and creates for every Stunde object this ics-"code". 
For help I have these NSDate formatting functions:

```
-(NSString*)nurTagFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *nurTag = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [nurTag setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    return [nurTag stringFromDate:date];
}

-(NSString*)nurUhrzeigFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *nurTag = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [nurTag setDateFormat:@"HHmmss"];
    return [nurTag stringFromDate:date];
}
```

As output I get something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//www.htw-dresden.de//iOS//DE
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:CCCAC9B3-E056-47E3-A63B-F2FE2C3BA454
DTSTART:20140318T111000Z
DTEND:20140318T124000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20140429T182723Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Internet-Technologien I
DESCRIPTION:Vogt\, J.
LOCATION:Z 254
END:VEVENT
.
.
.
END:VCALENDER
```

But the calendar app at my Mac don't want to open the file...

It would be great if some of you will have an Idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
[erg appendString:@"END:VCALENDER"];
```

With this:

```
[erg appendString:@"END:VCALENDAR"];
```

Notice the typo in VCALENDAR.

You may find this [iCal file validator](http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/) useful.

Comment: Thats embarrassing :D It was really only an typing issue.. Thank you so much, it worked :D